# Is there a way to add advanced seek and go to buttons in audio controls?

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I have been working with an audio player, and I can't  find a way to add "go to start and end" buttons, which would be necessary for the type of work I do. Is there a way to add this? The `<control>` tag does not help at all since it only adds the most basic controls. Also, it seems the environment I use does not accept/recognise `<div>` tags, so I'm at a loss here.

I tried the `<audio>` tag and some mp3 players, the first is too basic and the second usually make use of `<div>` tags, which my environment does not recognise.